# Is there any data structure that offers fast key/value access, but that is also ordered and can be accessed by a position index?

Tags: java, data-structures, key-value

Basically, I need something like a TreeMap but that would allow me to get the element at the position X efficiently.

Comment: @JeanLogeart ordered, because I need to be able to access the element at position X and if it were just sorted the index won't necessarily be the same as the position (as there could be gaps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`ListOrderedMap`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/ListOrderedMap.html) from [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/).

It gives you a `get(int index)` method to retrieve the key at position `index` on top of the usual `Map` methods.

Comment: That looks like it would be a nice solution to my problem. The link doesn't provide information on its performance though. Do you happen to know how fast is it?

Comment: It is ``O(1)`` for ``get(index)`` since it uses an ``ArrayList`` internally. The ``Map`` methods are the ones of the provided ``map``.

Comment: Good tip -- just note that if it uses an `ArrayList` internally, inserting and deleting key/value pairs will not scale well if the structure gets really large.

Answer (score 1):

A balanced tree can be used for both lookups by key and by index, both in O(log N) time, **if** you store a "size" field in each node which tracks how many key/value pairs are contained in the node *and* all its descendants.

The code for looking up a value by index would look something like this (in pseudocode):

```
 def at(index)
   if index == this.left.size
     return this.value
   else if index < this.left.size
     return this.left.at(index)
   else
     return this.right.at(index - this.left.size - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

TreeMap get complexity is O(log n)
I guess it is not a concern in performance.
Also as i know array has O(1) but the your demands match with treemap.

The SortedMap Interface with TreeMap is suitable for you :).

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be difficult to combine some data structures to provide this. Assuming there are no duplicates then the sketch below could work. If you do need to support duplicates then wrap your objects with something that provides unique hashes like the default Object class does.

I have no idea how you want use the positional data so I didn't add any methods that relate to reordering or iterating but it wouldn't be difficult. Sounds like the Apaches ListOrderedMap is a good choice too.

```
public class OrderedMap<K, V>{
        private ArrayList<V> values;
        private HashMap<K, V> map;
        private HashMap<K, Integer> keysToIndices;

        public OrderedMap(){
                values = new ArrayList<>();
                map = new HashMap<>();
                keysToIndices = new HashMap<>();
        }

        public void put(K key, V value){
                values.add(value);
                map.put(key, value);
                keysToIndices.put(key, values.size()-1);
        }
        public T get(K key){
                return map.get(key);
        }

        public V remove(K key){
                map.remove(key);
                return values.remove(keysToIndices.remove(key))
        }
}
```